# Is there any plugin or way to upload file to server using flutter web?

Tags: flutter-web

I want to upload image to the server from flutter web application. Is there any better way of doing that.

I've already tried with couple of plugins. 
image-picker, file-picker
But none of them are supported for flutter web.

Answer (score 21):

you can use the FileUploadInputElement class of dart:html.

The first thing to do is to import dart:html.

```
import 'dart:html';
```

Implement following code to start a file picker:

```
_startFilePicker() async {
InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
uploadInput.click();

uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
  // read file content as dataURL
  final files = uploadInput.files;
  if (files.length == 1) {
    final file = files[0];
    final reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
      _handleResult(reader.result);
    });
    reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
  }
});
}
```

Comment: any idea of making this on new flutter web?

Comment: @JuanJoseRodrigo, what's the problem? Just call this method from your FlatButton or whatever other place. Just tried it and it's working like a charm.

Comment: @JuanJoseRodrigo, not familiar with PHP. Are you trying to upload entire XLS into MySql? I guess you want to parse XLS first and then put data in MySql, not entire spreadsheet. .

Comment: In addition to the file selection from the above code you will probably want this piece to actually send the file to the server: https://gist.github.com/thetrav/eef0770f79ec29b682616fa63faae6fe

Comment: Does anyone know how to generate checksum of the File object from dart:html. Required parameters like filepath, byteSize, etc are not accessible. More details about the parameters https://pub.dev/packages/crypto. I tried converting the file content to base64 then re encode it into io.File from the universal_io package but to no consequences. Checksum generation is an issue. If anyone has any idea let me know, maybe I'll file this is a new question in SO.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty options at the moment. There is file_picker, drop_zone and so one.
This example works at the moment for files up to the size of 530MB.

```
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    VoidCallback openFilePicker = () async {

      FilePickerResult? result;
      print("pick files");
      result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true, withReadStream: true, withData: false);

      if (result != null) {
        print(result.files.first.name);

        //---Create http package multipart request object
        var request = http.MultipartRequest(
          "POST",
          Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/api/upload"),
        );


        List<PlatformFile>? files = result.files;


        if (files != null) {
          print("adding files selected with file picker");
          for (PlatformFile file in files) {
            //-----add selected file with request
            request.files.add(http.MultipartFile(
                "Your parameter name on server side",
                file.readStream!,
                file.size,
                filename: file.name));
          }
        }

        //-------Send request
        var resp = await request.send();

        //------Read response
        String result2 = await resp.stream.bytesToString();

        //-------Your response
        print(result2);

      }
    };


    TextButton selectAndSend = TextButton(onPressed: openFilePicker, child: Text("Selet and send"));


    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flutter bug example')),
          body: selectAndSend
          )
    );

  }
}
```