# How to get the name of file after being uploaded in flutter-web (ex. hello.pdf")

Tags: html, flutter, file-upload, upload, flutter-web

I would like know how to get the name of file and type that I have uploaded in flutter-web project. So, for example.. I would like to get the name like `hello.png` or `task_result.pdf`
So far, I have followed this [Choose a File and send through POST with Flutter Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761947/choose-a-file-and-send-through-post-with-flutter-web) to upload the file like this

```
startWebFilePicker() async {
    html.InputElement uploadInput = html.FileUploadInputElement();
    uploadInput.multiple = true;
    uploadInput.draggable = true;
    uploadInput.click();

    uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
      final files = uploadInput.files;
      final file = files[0];
      final reader = new html.FileReader();
      reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
        _handleResult(reader.result);
      });
      reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
    });
  }
```

but I stuck to get the name of the file.. is there a way to get the name of user's file that being uploaded to web?

Comment: Did you check if `file.name` property returns the name of the file.?

Comment: I have checked it yesterday and I got the name of file and the type from ```file``` property, thank you @AbhilashChandran